# Jest - Testing Module Multiple Times in One Test Suite

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have a TypeScript module (should be irrelevant, as I think this affect JS too) and I'm trying to test a module I have. The module imports lots of data from external files and chooses which data should be returned based on the a variable.

I'm attempting to run some tests where I update that variable, re-`require` the module and run further tests in one file. But my issue is that the `require` of the file only runs once. I guess it's being cached. Is it possible to tell Jest's `require` function not to cache or to clear the cache between tests?

Here's some stripped back code of what I'm trying to achieve:

module.ts

```
import { getLanguage } from "utils/functions";

import * as messagesEn from "resources/translations/en";
import * as messagesFr from "resources/translations/fr";

// Determine the user's default language.
const language: string = getLanguage();

// Set messages based on the language.
let messages: LocaleMessages = messagesEn.default;
if (languageWithoutRegionCode === "fr") {
    messages = messagesFr.default;
}

export { messages, language };
```

test.ts

```
import "jest";

// Mock the modules
const messagesEn = { "translation1": "English", "translation2": "Words" };
const messagesFr = { "translation1": "Francais", "translation2": "Mots" };
const getLangTest = jest.fn(() => "te-ST");
const getLangEn = jest.fn(() => "en-GB");
const getLangFr = jest.fn(() => "fr-FR");
jest.mock("resources/translations/en", () => ({"default": messagesEn}));
jest.mock("resources/translations/fr", () => ({"default": messagesFr}));
jest.mock("utils/functions", () => ({
        getLanguage: getLangTest
    })
);

describe("Localisation initialisation", () => {
    it("Sets language", () => {
        const localisation = require("./localisation");
        expect(getLangTest).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(localisation.language).toEqual("te-ST");
        expect(localisation.messages).toEqual(messagesEn);
    });

    it("Sets english messages", () => {
        // THIS GETS THE MODULE FROM THE CACHE
        const localisation = require("./localisation");
        expect(getLangEn).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(localisation.language).toEqual("en-GB");
        expect(localisation.messages).toEqual(messagesEn);
    });

    it("Sets french messages", () => {
        // THIS GETS THE MODULE FROM THE CACHE
        const localisation = require("./localisation");
        expect(getLangFr).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(localisation.language).toEqual("fr-FR");
        expect(localisation.messages).toEqual(messagesFr);
    });
});
```

I'm aware the second and third tests won't work anyway as I'd need to update the `"utils/functions"` mock. The issue is that the code in module.ts only runs once.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So, many thanks to the Jest folks on Discord. It's possible to actually clear the modules from the cache with the [`jest.resetModules()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#jestresetmodules) function.

So my test.ts file will look as follows:

```
describe("Localisation initialisation", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
    });

    it("Sets language", () => {
        const localisation = require("./localisation");
        // Perform the tests
    });

    it("Sets english messages", () => {
        const localisation = require("./localisation");
        // Perform the tests
    });

    it("Sets french messages", () => {
        const localisation = require("./localisation");
        // Perform the tests
    });
});
```

The `beforeEach()` call to `jest.resetModules()` ensures we're re-running the code in the module.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution! It's just what I needed.